# weblogic 10.3.5 installation error. Unrecognized option: -jrockit

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to install weblogic 10.3.5 in my machine. I downloaded it from this site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html and for 64 bit i took the generic downloads. Looks like JDK is not attacked to the jar so i had to specify the path during the installation. I pointed them to 64 bit JDK 1.7.0_05. The installation took just 3-5mins and it said it was successful but during the weblogic start i get this error and the console doesnt open.

```
Unrecognized option: -jrockit
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried couple of times but still i get the same issue. Any inputs?

Answer (score 11):

Even I had the same issue with Weblogic 11g and Oracle JDK 1.7. Since JVM was HotSpot Client, I changed the `JAVA_VM` option in the file "commEnv.cmd" under `:oracle`. Below is the extract from the file.

```
:oracle
if "%PRODUCTION_MODE%" == "true" goto oracle_prod_mode
set JAVA_VM=-client
```

And it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use JDK 1.6. When WebLogic server 10 was released there was no JDK 1.7. Maybe WebLogic run script does not recognize your environment and suppose that you have jrockit environment. Using JDK 1.6 should solve your problem.

**UPD** If you insist on using JDK 1.7 I suggest that you can try to find a problem place in server run/setEnv scripts and edit them to avoid jrockit option.

Comment: I want to use 1.7. Where can i find the error and how can i fix it? pls help.

Comment: I did not use JDK 1.7 for 10g server. I can suggest that you can try to edit $MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/domain_name/bin/startWebLogic.sh and $MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/domains/domain_name/bin/setDomainEnv.sh or equivalent bat scripts (I hope that you have created domain). Also you can try to find `-jrockit` option in script using text search. In Linux you can use command like this `find $MIDDLEWARE_HOME -name *.sh | xargs -I {} grep "-jrockit" {}`.

Comment: In WebLogic 12c I've found `-jrockit` option in file `./Middleware/wlserver_12.1/common/bin/commEnv.sh`. It seems that java vendor has changed from Sun to Oracle and `-jrockit` option was wrongly used. But you better check out your installation completely because there can be a lot of differences in scripts.